# What to look for when initial loss is high in Neural network training?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train my neural network for image classification using conv3d. While training I see the initial loss is more than 2. So I was wondering what could I do to reduce this initial loss ?

Here is my model code :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(2, (3,3,3), padding = 'same', input_shape= [num_of_frame, 
          img_rows,img_cols, img_channels] ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (3,3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I am using 30 as my batch size and image dimension is 120*90 with adam optimizer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the value of the initial loss being high.

Answer (score 1):

Your model's first layer is having a hard time detecting basic features since you have only 2 convolution kernels on the first layer which isn't a very good idea. also using 0.25 as a dropout rate is not very common.(values between 0.5 and 0.7 are more commonly used.)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for a very high loss in the first iteration is due to weights and bias initialization. Loss is calculated after each forward pass and the forward pass is a function of inputs, weight, bias and non-linearities.

As, the only nonlinearity in your network is in the output layer. I suspect this is due to the weights and bias initialization.